# Android: Why does the video abruptly pause when starting web speech recognition on Chrome?

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, video.js, webspeech-api

### Background

The issue at hand involves a scenario where a video abruptly stops playing when web speech recognition is initiated, triggering the 'pause' event in Video.js. Then, the video does not resume playback. Here are the results of my testing on various devices:

1. Android, Chrome - looping video **stops playing** when web speech recognition is initiated. Playback automatically resumes when speech recognition is stopped.
2. iOS Safari, Chrome - looping video **freezes, then resumes** playback when web speech recognition is initiated. Playback freezes a second when speech recognition is stopped.
3. Widows PC, Chrome - looping video **does not change** when web speech recognition is initiated, nor stopped.

### What I want

I want the video to continue playing (without freezing or pausing) when web speech recognition is used.

### Tech stack

- [React.js](https://react.dev/)
- [Video.js](https://videojs.com/)
- [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) wrapped by [react-speech-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition)

### Live demo and sample code

[sample with video and web speech](https://5rvsfc.csb.app/)

### What I tried

- I tried to see if the problem is with using the microphone, not the Web Speech API. So I turned on the mic only (`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })`). The video still does not stop playing, nor freeze.

It seems that there might be issues with the Web Speech API's starting process. Is this a possible bug in Android and iOS? Or is there a way to fix this issue?
Is there anyone who has experienced this issue and found a solution?

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue, what I did on Android is everytime it paused, I played it back: `player.on("pause", ()=>{player.play()})`. That is a super hacky way to get around the issue, but it works for now.